# Run multiple python scripts in different terminals

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

I have multiple python scripts
`task1.py` and `task2.py`. I want to run them simultaneously but in different Terminal windows on MAC OS. I have tried

```
python task1.py &
python task2.py &
```

but the two python scripts run in the same Terminal window, which makes it difficult to check the process.

how to do that?

Comment: Can you open two separate terminal windows? `cmd+n`

Comment: @DNy I can but I actually have 50 programs and I want to automatically run all codes.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run them simultaneously but on a different Terminal

In that case, you can either open a new terminal, which is ok.
The shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and then click the <kbd>+</kbd> sign. I prefer the use of [iTerm](https://iterm2.com/) on Mac.

Or, even better, you can use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Run the python1 script in a screen session. And the 2nd in another screen session.

Some basic commands:

```sh
# start a screen session
screen -S <name_your_screen>

#list screens sessions
screen -list

# attach to screen session
screen -r <pid>.<name_of_screen>
```

An alternative would be to use [tmux](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/tmux-1.html).